Video streaming is lagging too much while bluetooth headset is connected
I am struggling to watch videos online through browser from any site(including YouTube) while my Bluetooth headset is connected. It's giving neverending buffering, video pause after almost every 30 seconds. It works very fine on speaker. I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 and Firefox/Brave for browsing.
I've tried many solutions suggested online such as:

Refreshing the page multiple times and reconnecting my bluetooth device and also tried with alternate bluetooth device
Tweaking Hardware acceleration in browser
changing buffer size(latency using pactl set-port-latency-offset
restarting pipewire and wireplumber.service
tried reinstalling  pipewire-audio-client-libraries libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack wireplumber packages
system reboot after each aforementioned steps.

Now I'm really frustrated and looking for any help possible.

output of lshw -C net



Are you connected to internet using wifi?

@Jeremy31 Yes, I am using mobile hotspot from my smartphone.

Post results from terminal for lsusb|grep cfg

lsusb|grep cfg  outputs nothing. blank

Try lshw -C net

@Jeremy31:  updated the post with output requested. Please take a look.

You can try a module parameter echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k-bt.conf then reboot

Tried and failed. Again : (

I tweaked my mobile hotspot protocol from WPA2/WPA3-personal to WPA3-personal and it started working. Then reset to WPA2/WPA3-personal back and still working. Then removed etc/modprobe.d/ath9k-bt.conf and rebooted and it's not working again(without tweaking from WPA2/WPA3-personal this time). So, added the file back and now it's working good. Thanks @Jeremy31 for all the help. :-) Hope it keeps working.
